# Insert and position images along with text

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to create my personal blog. So there must be some images in my articles. When I add new article or edit existing one, I want to have some images in my article. But also I want to choose position of image by myself. Is there any tool that helps to insert images and place them between the text in admin?

Comment: You can use markdown language that can be installed via pip

Answer (score 0):

You can use rich editor like `django-wysiwyg`. `https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg` as follow:

```
pip install django-wysiwyg
```

Add 'django_wysiwyg' to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_wysiwyg',
)
```